# Sql query triggered twice

Tags: wpdb

I am trying to collect data from a search box. Conditions; if the value exists, update the counter field based on how many times it's been searched.

Problem: when a duplicate value searched in the form, the counter value increases by 2 not 1. So, if its current value is 5 and the term has been searched again the value in the database updated to 7, not 6. Any idea on the cause?

```
function content_filter( $where, $wp_query ){

    global $wpdb;
    if ( $search_term = $wp_query->get( 'search_prod_content' ) ) {
        $where .= ' AND ' . $wpdb->posts . '.post_content LIKE \'%' . esc_sql(  $search_term  ) . '%\'';        

    }


    // first check if data exists with select query

    $datum = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM search_product WHERE TERM = '".$search_term."'");
    if($wpdb->num_rows > 0) {


    $sql = $wpdb->prepare(
    "UPDATE search_product SET COUNTER = COUNTER + 1  WHERE TERM = '".$search_term."'");

    $wpdb->query($sql);


    }
    // if not exist in the database then insert it
    else{

        $now = new DateTime();
        $datesent=$now->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');  
        $sql = $wpdb->prepare(
         "INSERT INTO `search_product` (`TERM`,`DATE`) values (%s,%s)", 
          $search_term, $datesent);

        $wpdb->query($sql);
      }



    return $where;
}
```

Comment: You should first check if the value already exists in the database and if not, only then you insert the value.

Comment: Did what you suggested but getting a different error this time. Please check the description.

Comment: Please check and try the suggestions in my answer. And do let me know if the problem is solved.. OK? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Try Applying These Changes

1. Add this conditional *before* the `// first check if data exists with select query`:

   ```
   // Do nothing else if the search term is empty.
   if ( empty( $search_term ) ) {
       return $where;
   }
   ```

   *Update:* You may also want to check if it's the *main query* and if not, exit the function:

   ```
   if ( empty( $search_term ) ||        // missing search term
       ! $wp_query->is_main_query() ) { // or not the main query
       return $where;
   }
   ```
2. I would *not* <strike>do `SELECT *` (select all) records</strike> use `$wpdb->get_results()` just to check if an existing entry for a search term exists in the database or not. Secondly, you should've used `$wpdb->prepare()` instead of the `TERM = '".$search_term."'`. So I'd replace this:

   ```
   $datum = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM search_product WHERE TERM = '".$search_term."'");
   if($wpdb->num_rows > 0) {
   ```

   with this:

   ```
   $sql = $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT TERM FROM search_product WHERE TERM = %s LIMIT 1", $search_term );
   if ( $wpdb->get_var( $sql ) ) {
   ```
3. Again in this code, you should've *not* used `TERM = '".$search_term."'`. So I'd replace this:

   ```
   $sql = $wpdb->prepare(
   "UPDATE search_product SET COUNTER = COUNTER + 1  WHERE TERM = '".$search_term."'");
   ```

   with this:

   ```
   $sql = $wpdb->prepare( "UPDATE search_product SET COUNTER = COUNTER + 1 WHERE TERM = %s", $search_term );
   ```
4. And the code after the `// if not exist in the database then insert it` can be rewritten to:

   ```
   else {
       $wpdb->insert( 'search_product', [
           'TERM'    => $search_term,
           'DATE'    => current_time( 'mysql' ),
       //  'COUNTER' => 1, // <- uncomment if the default value of the column is not 1
       ] );
   }
   ```

Comment: Could you please check the fourth part again? I am getting an error when I replace the code with mine

Comment: Not sure if you still need help, but if you do, then let me know what error is it? Because I'm not getting any errors.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the Search form inserted twice in your website. It may stupid answer but you should check it first.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. Thank you very much for your help with this.

PS: I found another article on this topic related to prefetches. Basically, to avoid the query runs twice on your page, folks are mentioning to add the following code to your function.php file.

```
function remove_dns_prefetch($hints, $relation_type)
{
    if ('dns-prefetch' === $relation_type) {
        return array_diff(wp_dependencies_unique_hosts(), $hints);
    }
    return $hints;
}
```

Another quick note: when I search the same term on the same browser, the counter is not increasing. However, if I go incognito or use another browser and search the same term, then the counter is increasing.